# MarionetteJS : upgraded to 2.4.0 from 2.3.2 and getting an error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Just upgraded (by replacing my marionette.js file) from 2.3.2 and 2.4.0 (also tried 2.4.1) and I'm getting an "undefined is not a function" error.

The console is pointing at line 225 of BackboneJS (1.1.2), which is below (starting with `obj[implementation.....]`

```
  _.each(listenMethods, function(implementation, method) {
    Events[method] = function(obj, name, callback) {
      var listeningTo = this._listeningTo || (this._listeningTo = {});
      var id = obj._listenId || (obj._listenId = _.uniqueId('l'));
      listeningTo[id] = obj;
      if (!callback && typeof name === 'object') callback = this;
      obj[implementation](name, callback, this); !!!!! <- this LINE
      return this;
    };
  });
```

I'm using CollectionView and ItemView, and they're pretty simple.

```
class TableRow extends Mn.ItemView
  tagName   : "tr"
  template  :Handlebars.compile $("#table-row-template").html()

class TablePanel extends Mn.CollectionView
  childView    : TableRow

  initialize: (options) =>
    @collection = options
```

Any ideas??

Comment: is options a Backbone Collection because it looks like it is trying to go through the listening methods that a collection view setups by default on the collection and failing because the object is not a backbone collection

Comment: Silly me. you're right. Options is an object, so I shouldn't do a direct assignment for @collection = options... and Marionette by default assigns collection if it exists in the options anyway.